# Why applications on FreeBSD run slower than on Linux?

Tags: linux, freebsd, performance, trueos

### Update

They don't! At least, not for me.

See my answer.

### Original question

According to [last year's Phoronix benchmarks](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=freebsd-12-windows&num=4), applications on FreeBSD mostly run slower than on Debian (including Stockfish chess engine, Node.js, FLAC encoding and other computational tasks).

Phoronix article itself attributes some of the performance differences to use of Clang instead of GCC compiler. [Some other](https://www.quora.com/Is-FreeBSD-faster-than-Linux/answer/Ben-Lunsford) opinions say that use of ZFS makes FreeBSD slower, as ZFS is inherently slower than ext4.

But even purely computational tasks on FreeBSD compiled with GCC8 performed slower than on Linux.

What is the cause of that? Is it inherent to differences between FreeBSD and Linux kernels, might it be caused by worse quality of drivers or is there some other reason?

**P.S.** To make it more specific, here is a fairly simple purely computational program that runs slower on FreeBSD than on Linux according to Phoronix: [m-queens 1.2](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/benchmark-files/m-queens-1.2.tar.gz). Compiled like this:

```
gcc -o m-queens.bin main.c -O2 -march=native -mtune=native -std=c99 -fopenmp
```

Since this a multithreaded task that was run on two 20 core CPUs, I suspect the performance difference boils down to how well OS handles multiple threads.

**P.P.S.** To make it more clear, I am aware that FreeBSD has [good networking capabilities](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=windows-linux-10gbe&num=4) and that it is [used by Netflix](https://fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/netflix_freebsd/). The question is specifically about computational tasks, like the one above.

**P.P.P.S.** After installing FreeBSD (TrueOS) on my 6-core desktop alongside Ubuntu and trying to run the queens benchmark myself, I didn't notice any significant difference in multithreaded performance. While Phoronix claims that it ran 39% slower on FreeBSD, in my tests it was only 3.7% slower, which could be attributed to slight difference in compiler version (gcc 7.4 on TrueOS, gcc 7.2 on Ubuntu). I will test more later.

Comment: Note to people who may consider answering: Unless answered by someone with real in-depth knowledge of the two systems (and of the actual benchmarks used), this question may generate pure speculation and personal opinion. Let's try to avoid as much of that as possible.

Comment: Why the downvote? I just try to understand the difference…

Comment: I don't see why your question should be downvoted either. So I've upvoted it.
If you care enough, you should be able to answer the question yourself: boot the same machine into FreeBSD and into Linux. Take one of the computational tasks that is slower on FreeBSD and start disecting it into smaller parts until you have only the few lines left that behave differently.
A few things that might cause the difference between the OSes: CPU cache management, system call overhead, slightly different function call conventions, scheduler overhead, security (stack canaries, ASLR, page zeroing, etc.)

Comment: Take benchmarks with a grain of salt. Often what it matters in the real world does not translate directly in benchmarks be it user friendliness, capability of scaling, support and politics. The question in itself *is interesting*, but might be too broad as it is. I would look a bit into Netflix and why they go with FreeBSD, for examples in the real world.

Comment: Too board. Does program run slower on FreeBSD? That's actually non-sense without mentioning what program we're referring to. The same piece of C/Rust/Go or whatever language will compiled to different machine code on different platform, so they doom to have performance difference. So-called purely computational tasks usually also contain IO and OS task scheduling, which is platform dependent. It is simply not possible that every piece of code run slower on FreeBSD.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek, yes, I was already thinking which machine to use to install FreeBSD (or TrueOS) for testing. But I thought, maybe someone already had the answer...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, my understanding is that FreeBSD has very fast networking and that is the reason why Netflix chose it at some point.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克, my question is specific to computational tasks (I tried to make that clear). If you want a specific program: [m-queens 1.2](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/benchmark-files/m-queens-1.2.tar.gz)

Comment: Without knowing your program, there is no way to answer this question. To point out the fallacy of using benchmarks as a foundation, Netflix distributes all their video via FreeBSD. If FreeBSD was slower, why did they choose it over Linux? In this case, a real world application runs *faster* on FreeBSD.

Comment: @Rob, I know that FreeBSD network stack is very fast. That is the advantage. Particularly, Phoronix also reported that. The question is about computationally intense applications as opposed to networking.

Comment: The operating system runs the network stack. My point, however, is that one cannot rely on benchmarks to prove application performance.

Comment: @Rob, I don't think you are right. These specific benchmarks are exactly the applications that I use in my daily life, like music encoder, web server or chess engine. I don't want to install FreeBSD on my laptop to stream terabytes of videos. But I'd like file archives to generate faster. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: The problem is that most of us don't have **two** spare **identical** 20-core machines to play with, so any answer will be a mix of biased/incomplete/irrelevant data, speculation and folklore ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, but someone might have a 6-core CPU at home standing there with both Ubuntu and FreeBSD installed :) Just to confirm or refute once and for all these "unfair benchmarks".

Comment: Anyways, in the case of those perl benchmark, I suspect that they used different configurations -- otherwise that big difference between linux and windows is not justified. Last time I tried, a perl built with threads support (**not** the default on linux distros) was ridiculously slow, orders of magnitude slower on some task. Building perl as a shared lib with support for multiple interpreters ("multiplicity") also makes it slower, because each C function from its implementation will have an extra argument passed.

Comment: Also, I suspect that even after they got rid of phkmalloc on FreeBSD, the malloc on Linux is still much faster for silly tasks like repeatingly realloc()ating a buffer with increasingly larger sizes, something that unfortunately `perl` is doing a lot. CS-educated people are loath of optimizing their nice things for such idiotic usage patterns, and they may fail phoronix benchmarks because of that ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, from my experience, different Python installations also differ significantly in performance, so I don't think any Per/PHP/Python benchmarks are a good indicator of OS performance. However, I did install Perl 5.30 from sources and tried to run those Perl benchmarks. I was surprised to learn that the same benchmark script runs on FreeBSD, but throws a syntax error on Ubuntu.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Far more than the network. It scales way much better under very heavy loads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So many downvotes stimulated me to install FreeBSD (TrueOS) on my 6-core desktop computer to test it myself. (NOTE: I do not recommend trying to install TrueOS alongside other operating systems, because this installation wiped one of my hard drives, even though I tried to install it on a USB drive... Not a user-friendly experience.)

As a result, after running some tests from the Phoronix test suite on both Ubuntu and FreeBSD, I couldn't see the “slow applications on FreeBSD” effect. Quite the contrary, **some applications ran significantly (10–25%) faster on FreeBSD**:

```
    Test                                    FreeBSD 13        Ubuntu 17
Fhourstones, kpos/s                       16753             13336
m-queens, multithreaded, user time, s     18.08             17.38
7zip 1 GB text file, user time, s         994               1096
```

As you can see, the only task that performed slower on FreeBSD was multithreaded N queens problem, taking 3.7% more time than on Ubuntu.

Potential pitfalls:

- gcc on Ubuntu was version 7.2, on FreeBSD – 7.4
- Ubuntu was running with KDE, FreeBSD in a shell (shouldn't make much difference)
- Phoronix used 80-thread server, I used 6-thread Intel i5 computer.

In conclusion, when testing OS performance, you should:

- run benchmarks on your setup yourself instead of trusting results that were obtained by someone else.
- try to use the same compiler.
- beware that performance of scripting languages like Perl and Python are not a good indicator of OS performance, since different installations of the interpreters behave differently.

Comment: Are those averaged across multiple runs? How many?

Comment: @muru, three runs, best performance reported. In all cases the difference between runs was insignificant.

Comment: Anecdotal cautionary tale, they dub it "Moronix" for some reason. While useful, take what you read there with a pinch of salt. Upvoted both answer and question for you taking the trouble to investigating the issue. https://jonimoose.net/2013/moronix-why-amd-wont-take-michael-larabel-seriously-and-you-shouldnt-either/ and http://lxer.com/module/forums/t/31292/

Comment: (coming back: see Brendan Gregg or the DragonFlyBSD site for benchmarking done right)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, wow! This controversy with FreeBSD and Phoronix goes back like 10 years in time! However, if Phoronix gets these bad results for FreeBSD so consistently, doesn't that mean that there is at least partial truth to these allegations? I would be very interested to see a new modern "anti-Phoronix" benchmark that would either explain why Phoronix gets such bad results for FreeBSD or just show that FreeBSD doesn't perform inferior when retested in similar setting.

Answer (score 3):

I see, the benchmark involves using OpenMP. This is where difference may come from. Check what OpenMP runtime library is being used.

Another thing worth looking at - disassembly code or intermediate representation. It can allow you to quickly find differences in instructions being executed.

To sum this up, there is no quick and definitive answer to this, and you have to do some research.

Comment: Yeah, I'll research. I hoped that someone had an answer already, because this is only one of multitude tasks that seem to run slower on FreeBSD.

Comment: I also heard controversial opinions on Phoronix benchmarks quality.

Comment: But what is the controversy? I tried to find explanation on FreeBSD forums, but couldn't find anything of substance.

Comment: For example, here is an independent benchmark that comes to a similar conclusion: [PostgreSQL benchmark on FreeBSD, CentOS, Ubuntu Debian and openSUSE](https://redbyte.eu/en/blog/postgresql-benchmark-freebsd-centos-ubuntu-debian-opensuse/?utm_source=discoverbsd). PostgreSQL works slower even for read-only operations.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha "Seems to run slower"? Are you referring to the benchmark results or to something _you_ are running?

Comment: @Kusalananda, so far I am not running anything on FreeBSD because I couldn't install it on two of my laptops. So I am referring to benchmarks that someone else did (hence "seems", because I did not confirm yet).

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Got it running in a Lenovo and two Asus ;)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I figured, that only one 8-years old laptop fails to host TrueOS. To be more precise, the installer reboots each time I try to run it on that machine. On another laptop hardware scan before installation just doesn't detect a network device. However, this is probably just a bad user interface of the installer, because on my desktop it also couldn't detect network device at that stage, but installed properly and the Internet works.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I have got Freebsd 11.x 32-bits running in a 2009 Asus that I use for tests. Are you not forgetting that a machine of that era might not be 64 bits?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, no, it has 64-bit Intel Core i7-2720QM. Moreover, first x86-64 processors appeared back in 2003 ;) The installer runs, but crashes at some point.